# Neutering incisions in cat

Tags: cats, health, safety, surgery, wound-care

My kitten just got neutered today and he has been bad about trying to lick his incision. I put a cone on him but he is able to pull it off. How easily is he able to ruin his incisions?

He is on pain medication.

Comment: This question is relevant: [How can I stop my cat from removing her cone?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/how-can-i-stop-my-cat-from-removing-her-cone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is best if your cat avoids licking the wound for a couple of weeks as it heals.

The chance for the incision to be infected is not large, but it is best to be sure it does not happen.

So you need to put the cone back on and a little tighter this time; where I live the vets do often avoid putting on a cone, but do send the cone home with the cat in case it is needed, and in your cat's case it is needed.

An incision like your cat has will heal quite fast, but this is dependent on your cat's age; if it is done on a kitten before maturity, it heals quicker than if it is an adult cat.

Comment: There are usually no sutures with a cat neuter, incisions are very small and left to heal by second intention

Comment: @HarryV. thank you for the information the last time i had a cat neutered was a 10yo feral and my vet made a couple of sutures on him but i might be mistaken he had surgery in the mouth and belly at the same time as the neutering.

Comment: It's possible in a large tom if the incisions were very large, then sutures could have been placed. Just most cases (especially kittens) have no sutures

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to prevent kitten from licking sutures - put them in a human baby onesie.  They do sell ones for kittens in pet stores, but you can do this on the cheap if you have an old, tight baby onesie.  Just make sure the opening in the bottom is big enough for the tail, and if needed, just snip a hole with scissors.

Another option to [buy or create one from a T-shirt is outlined in this answer by Zaralynda](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/how-can-i-stop-my-cat-from-removing-her-cone/6414#6414)

yet another option is this one https://www.ebay.com/p/KRUUSE-Buster-Bodysuits-for-Cats-Outfit-XXS-13-5-in/2055897354?_trksid=p2047675.l2644

Comment: Not sure this is such a good idea.. most cats aren't keen on being clothed and if the kitten objects to the onesie they are going to be thrashing around like mad to try and get it off and that's going to risk doing a fair bit of damage to the healing incision.

Comment: I think this might be a good answer, and I believe we have another post someplace about the vet supplied version of this for cats. Finding and linking that post in your answer would help improve the perceived quality of this answer.

Comment: @JamesJenkins There is something like [this](https://medicalpetshirts.com/products/medical-pet-shirt/) but I remain dubious, some cats seem to get on with them and others utterly hate them and get very distressed. I've also read reports that some cats have trouble walking in them! So I think they can work but YMMV

Comment: @motosubatsu I found what I was looking for and added it to the answer. Notice the author of the linked answer is the only [gold badge holder for cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/badges/121/cats)