# Cat incision opened up after neutering

Tags: cats, infections, neutering, wound-care

My 6 month old male cat was neutered 5 days ago. Since we have to go on a trip tomorrow morning and he's going to be alone for 2 days, I removed his Elizabeth collar an hour ago so that he can be comfortable and eat properly. Since then, he's been licking his incision and I checked and saw that there's a little blood on his incision and he keeps on licking it. He has received antibiotic shots during the first days to avoid infection and he had no swelling or redness or bleeding prior to this. Since the incision is very small and the bleeding is very little, should I leave him like that or should I put his collar back on? Is there anything I could rub on that area to prevent infections and prevent him from licking?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend leaving a pet completely alone post-surgery, and especially in an e-collar. I'd strongly suggest boarding or getting a sitter, _after_ consulting your vet about the bleeding.

Answer (score 3):

If the operation was done only 5 days ago, you shouldn't remove the cone. Your cat **will** lick the wound open, no question. You need to keep the collar on him for one more week.

Imagine cutting your hand. How long would it take for the skin to heal properly? After 5 days there might be fresh skin grown back, but it's still very tender and thin and most of all sensitive and itchy. That's why your cat licks the incision. And of course the rough texture of a cat tongue will irritate and damage this new skin in no time.

Also he schouldn't be alone for 2 days when he has the cone on. It could make it harder for him to eat, drink and move around. If possible, please get a family member or friend to look after him several times a day. Otherwise get him a place in a cat hotel.

There are some more comfortable alternatives to an Elizabethan collar, [please read this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6412/12501).